# Build Flow vs Build Pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, build-process, build-automation

I'm trying to split up a few Jenkins jobs using the [Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) plugin so that instead of three monolithic jobs, we have three "starting points" that then use the DSL to trigger downstream jobs. I chose Build Flow over the Build Pipeline plugin because it seemed like it was a lot harder to share jobs between different pipelines ( ie, sharing the workspace of the multiple starting jobs with a single compile job ).

Previously, I had three jobs set up: Project-PR, Project-DEV, and Project-PROD.

Project-PR would build whenever a pull request happened in GitHub, and would just run a smaller subset of our unit tests, so that we could get quick verification that the PR is okay to merge.

Project-DEV would build whenever a feature branch was merged in GitHub into the main development branch, as well as having the ability to be manually triggered and given a different branch to pull. It would run the full suite of unit -- basically a sanity check that everything is still good. Then it would compile and minify, and push to a QA environment for testing, and then it would run the full suite of integration tests against that QA environment. This step was configured as a parametrized build, with the parameter being the name of the branch to pull, test, and push. It would push to and set up QA environment specific to that branch, so that we could QA multiple features without having to merge to development ( ie, feature-one.qa.example.com, feature-two.qa.example.com ).

Project-PROD would only ever be manually triggered, and would do the full unit and integration test suite, compile and minify the front-end code ( Less, JS, and CSS ), and push the built code into a special "release branch" in GitHub that can then be deployed -- we haven't quite reached the point of Jenkins being in charge of deployment.

Now, what I wanted to set up was to split the subtasks into their own jobs, so that it'd be easy to set up new jobs to without having to copy and paste all the build steps ( or copying the job and changing all the things that need to be unique ). This would let us do things like create a copy of the Project-DEV, but switch out the last job for one that deploys to a staging environment set up in the cloud. Or easily create a job that could report test results to a third party source, ie copy the results to a shared network folder or something. Or any number of things. The goal is basically to use these subtask jobs as building blocks to let us build more complicated jobs, while also making it easier to update how one portion of the build works ( for example, maybe we switch to a different technology for compiling, which might change how Jenkins would compile the code ).

For example, the Project-PR would be split into the following:

```
Project-PULL -> Project-SetupBuildEnv -> Project-PartialUnitTests
(BuildFlow)     (Normal Job)             (Normal Job)
```

The SetupBuildEnv would just pull down any NPM or Composer requirements, and set up the directories required for testing and building. PartialUnitTests then run, and report it's results back up to the

The Project-DEV could be split up like so:

```
Project-DEV -> Project->SetupBuildEnv -> Project-FullUnitTests  -> Project-Compile -> Project-Minify -> Project-DeployQA -> Project-FullIntegrationTests
```

This way, the parts of the build process that are shared ( in this case, Project-SetupBuildEnv ) can be easily shared between jobs, reducing duplication, and making it easier to update a step in the build process without having to remember EVERY job that uses that step.

Right now, I'm using the [Shared Workspace](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin) plugin so that all the steps use the same workspace. However, I'm running into an issue with that: it's not actually using one workspace. What's happening is that the Build Flow job will get a directory ( eg: /sharedspace/shared_one ), and download the code from GitHub into there. Then it will trigger the DSL, which starts up the 'SetupBuildEnv' job. But instead of working inside the same directory, it will get a directory with a name like "/sharedspace/shared_one@2", and run the build setup task in there. Then when it goes to do the third step ( unit testing ), it fails, because now it's got a third directory ( /sharedspace/shared_one@3 ), but that directory didn't have the setup run, so the required node and composer modules are missing. What's weird is that it looks like the Shared Workspace plugin is copying the first shared workspace to another directory and incrementing a counter ( the @N part of the directory name ) and giving that to the other jobs to work in.

So, question time:

1. is there a way to fix the Shared Workspace plugin so that it's actually only using one directory for each job?
2. if not, is it possible to have the Clone Workspace plugin take an argument, so I can specify what archived workspace to use instead of using the dropdown?
3. another possiblity: would using the shared workspace plugin, but use the "Local subdirectory for repo (optional)" option in the advanced git job options to specify the directory to use?
4. failing all that, is there some other way to set up a build pipeline that can share jobs with other pipelines that I've missed out on?

Comment: Did you try to use the 'Use custom workspace' option on your jobs? Don't know if you can even parametrize workspace path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, even if you *do* get this working, this might not be a scalable way to go longer term. We've found the shared workspace plugin entirely a bad idea for long / complex builds (similar reasons to yours - but also: scaling across dozens of slaves becomes hard suddenly). Arguably the idea is slightly against the spirit of modern scalable CI.

I'd instead delegate more to your build tools, be they Maven / Gradle, Ant, even Grunt, whatever. If you want to keep these builds truly modular, but can't afford to rebuild at each step (we decided full independence was worth wasting a few minutes per build) then perhaps look at creating useful artefacts at key stages - in your case, minified assets TARs, library JARs, or maybe [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/), or whatever, and deploy *them* to a (Maven?) repo.

Later build steps in your pipeline can quickly, easily, and repeatably pull the latest (or named version) assets from this centralised repo, and continue with the build process.

An alternative (with similarities) is to build one or more assets, but only *promote* them after increasing numbers of tests are run, which can be done in separate builds coordinated by your build flow, using the [Promoted Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) etc.

Comment: A few minutes per build might be acceptable but rebuilding large C++ projects could be more like a few hours.